80s movie with a young girl falling in love for the first time
The movie I'm looking for is about a young girl (about 12) who falls in love for the first time. She meets this older boy (about 16) and they become friends. She also has an older sister (also about 16 I think). One night the young girl sees her sister and the boy kissing, which makes her very upset and she runs away from home. I'm not very sure, but I think the boy dies in an accident, while they are searching for her.
Additional details: I also remember scenes at a lake. The movie is English-spoken, and came out in the 80s.  I think the story itself is set in the 60s. The boy is dark haired and the young girl has long blonde hair.

Easy one! You are talking about THE MAN IN THE MOON with Reese Witherspoon. It came out in 1991, but otherwise your description fits exactly.

Rural Louisiana, summer of 1957, Elvis is King. At 14, Dani is coming of age. Her older sister is beautiful, smart, and off to Duke in the fall; her mom's pregnant with number four (Dad wants a son), and Dad's pretty strict. Life gets sweeter when 17-year-old Court Foster, his widowed mom, and two little brothers move into the vacant farm next door. Court likes Dani's high spirits and direct way, and though he has a man's responsibilities on the farm, they go off swimming sometimes. The waters of adolescence are deeper than Dani realizes as hers and Court's feelings get jumbled. Then Mother Nature throws wrenching surprises at Dani, and she must come to terms with new emotions.


YES that's the one ! As soon as I read the title I knew that's the movie I was looking for. Thanx !  Can't wait to see it again, with my 14-year old daughter now :-)
